# How I can generate payment number as unique?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, paypal

When you pay by paypal you receive payment number (as this `PAY-8YW005202J095132TLI5UVIE`) and I think this number is unique.
The question is how I can generate as this unique id, 
I work on system and this system save all transaction in DB into Transaction table and I want generate transaction number
I build structure for this payment as this

```
(year part)(month part)(day in the month part)(*)
```

the problem in (*) part I want generate random and unique number for each day.
I work on EF6 with C#.Net

Comment: What's the requirements? Length of an output string, its cryptographic strength...?

Comment: Do you want a random number or do you want a unique number because those are two different things.

Comment: thank you , i want unique number but i was ask about method to generate unique number by random, and i need plane text without any cryptographic.

Comment: Just use a guid

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I think you can use Random feature in C#.
 Random rnd = new Random();
 rnd.Next(); // This is always unique as the value depends on date and time, which is continuously changing.
Since Random usage has some disadvantages and as many people suggested, i am updating my answer.

Here is another way which you can generate unique key: DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMddHHmmssff"); Here are more details about string format: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx

Comment: thank you , but i would like ask you is this function return unique  even i have a huge request at the same time?

Comment: How many digits are you looking for? There is another way which you can generate unique key:              
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMddHHmmssff");                                                          Here are more details about string format: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx

Comment: Because `new Random()` uses the date and time to generate a seed, calling it in a loop or at the same date and time is [guaranteed to give you duplicates](https://weblogs.asp.net/smehaffie/random-number-in-c-be-careful-of-some-of-the-samples-you-find). Also, `Random.Next()` has [inadequate domain](https://betterexplained.com/articles/understanding-the-birthday-paradox/) to give unique values for any significant number of calls.

Comment: thank you i use this format (year symbol)(month symbol)(day)(HH)(mm)(ss)(ffffff)

Comment: This answer is dangerously incorrect.   In addition to the previously stated reasons, the return type of `Random.Next()` is `Int32`, so you can only have 
a pool of 2,147,483,647 positive values before you are completely out of unique values.  This may seem large, but it really isn't (since each time you use a value, the pool shrinks).   A `Guid`, by comparison, has 5,316,911,983,139,663,491,615,228,241,121,400,000  different possible combinations.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Guid` (global unique identifier). Try this:

```
var randomPart = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

also, you can control it presentation, like this:

```
var p = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")
    .Substring(0, 5); // note: trimming chars from guid make it less unique
```

this will create a string without dashes and 5 chars only.

Edit: Another options is `base64` string. You may try something like this:

```
var buffer = new byte[42]; // length is up to you
var random = RNGCryptoServiceProvider.Create();
random.GetBytes(buffer);
var randomPart = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
```

Comment: Careful, substrings of GUIDs are [not necessarily unique](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080627-00/?p=21823/).

Comment: @DourHighArch you are right - trimming chars from guid  make it less unique. However sometimes it's acceptable. Thanks for comment!

Answer (score 2):

Never use Random() to create a unique identifier.  Its results are not predictably unique.   There's a GUID (Globally Unique Identifier) object for a reason, and this is the reason.

```
var id = new Guid(); //call the ToString() method on this to get it as a string
```

That said, there is a chance you'll get duplicate Guid keys.  The chance is less likely than someone throwing a ball in space and hitting a comet without aiming, but the chance is there.  if you're particularly worried about that tiny chance, do something like this pseudocode:

```
var id = new Guid();
while(myGuidArrayThatIGotFromMyDatabase.Contains(id))
{ id = new Guid(); }
```

And if you end up in an infinite loop with that code because you keep matching existing data, I'm going to have to ask you to mine Bitcoin, be my official representative in Vegas, and pick a bunch of lottery tickets for me.

Also, while I mention above that you can .ToString() this to get the string equivalent of the GUID, it's important to note that not only does Guid(string value) exist as a Guid constructor, but also that a SQL Server database (and some others) will all support a Guid as a column value type in tables, which can eliminate your need to use strings for identifiers in the first place.